# Does Luke Skywalker know the lightsaber technique known as "Ataru" (Form IV)?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I was reading a blog and it mentioned that [Crimson Empire III](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Crimson_Empire_III%3a_Empire_Lost) states that Luke received Form IV training from Yoda. Is this true?

Comment: According to wookiepedia, "Grand Master Luke Skywalker also had knowledge and skill in the use of Ataru. Skywalker learned the form from Yoda and passed it on to his students, teaching them to embrace it not as a weapon of first use and to use both their weapon and their body in practicing Ataru. ". Are you looking for cases where he used it?

Comment: Yes I would like that

Comment: In the novels it does not really say Luke engaged his opponent using the Ataru style.  Instead it descibes him leaping through the air, spinning, and slicing.  It happens quite frequently in the EU especially in the Legacy of the Force series where he is facing Sith regularly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Wikia Ataru article](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Form_IV%3a_Ataru#cite_note-JATM-1), *[Jedi Academy Training Manual](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Academy_Training_Manual)* states that Luke was proficient in Ataru.

Just to clarify, Ataru and "Form IV" are the same thing (in other words, there are no 4 different forms of Ataru - there are different forms of Lightsaber combat and Ataru is a name given to Form IV)